# Functions in Lua could store local values between calls?

Tags: lua, closures

I'm reading "Programming in Lua" and I don't understand behavior of function in Lua in this piece of code:

```
function newCounter ()
  local i = 0
  return function () -- anonymous function
    i = i + 1
    return i
    end
end

c1 = newCounter()
print(c1()) --> 1
print(c1()) --> 2
```

From my point of view each call `c1()` should return `1` because `i` is initialized to zero at the beginning of the of `newCounter()`. But it looks like line

```
local i = 0
```

is skipped in calls of `c1()`. And `newCounter()` behaves like object not like function. I know Scheme and C# a little, so I am familiar with first-class functions. Function return function it's ok for me, but how does it stores value of `i` between calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the difference between a "normal" function and a **closure**.

To the anonymous function, `i` is NOT a local variable, it's not global either. It's called a non-local variable. Note that `i` is out of scope when you execute the anonymous function:

```
print(c1()) --> 1
print(c1()) --> 2
```

The point here is, the value of `i` is *stored* in the anonymous function. The function, and all the non-local variables, together make a closure.

Comment: Moreover, `i` is initialised in `newCounter()`, not in the increment anonymous function that is returned.

Comment: I add "i" as watch and start debugging this function in ZeroBrane Studio and it shows that i=nil between calls of c1(). How could that be?

Comment: @corund `i` is out of scope when the function `newCounter` has returned. You can think as if the returned closure has an independent instantiation of `i`. Try creating another closure `c2 = newCounter()` and play with both.

Comment: In the interpreter/REPL, you can try `return debug.getupvalue( c1, 1 )` or even e.g. `debug.setupvalue( c1, 1, -5 )` to experiment with this. (`i` is the first upvalue / non-local variable of the closure `c1`, hence the `1` as index.)

Answer (score 0):

you can treat `i` as a global variable only visible by `C1`.

Comment: `c2 = newCounter()` would have a different `i`. (So, I wouldn't use the term "global".)